# Compare the integrals $I=\int_{0}^{1}2^{x^2}dx\;,J=\int_{0}^{1}2^{x^3}dx\;,K=\int_{1}^{2}2^{x^2}dx\;,L=\int_{1}^{2}2^{x^3}dx$

Tags: calculus

Let $\displaystyle I=\int_{0}^{1}2^{x^2}dx\;\;\;\;\;\;,\; J = \int_{0}^{1}2^{x^3}dx\;\;\;\;\;\;,\; K=\int_{1}^{2}2^{x^2}dx\;\;\;\;\;\;,\;,L=\int_{1}^{2}2^{x^3}dx\;\;\;\;\;\;,\;  $

Then arrange $I,J,K,L$ in increasing order.

$\bf{My\; Try}.$ We know that if $0<x<1$, then $x^3<x^2$. So $2^{x^{3}}<2^{x^{2}}$

So $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{1}2^{x^{3}}dx< \int_{0}^{1}2^{x^{2}}dx\Rightarrow J<I$

in $1<x<2$ interval $x^2<x^3$. So $2^{x^{2}}<2^{x^{3}}$

So $\displaystyle \int_{1}^{2}2^{x^{2}}dx< \int_{1}^{2}2^{x^{3}}dx\Rightarrow K<L$

Now I did not understand How can I prove $K>I$

Help Required

Thanks

oh sorry I mean how can I prove $K>J$

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

$ K> I $ because $2^{x^2}$ on $[1, 2] \geq 2^{x^2}$ on $[0, 1] $

Comment: You have already proved that $ I>J $, so $ K> I> J $

Comment: I did not noticed that, Thanks Elensil.

Answer (score 1):

let t = x-1 then K = Int(0->1)[2^((t+1)^2)]dt > Int(0->1)[2^(t^2)]dt = I.

Comment: Thanks NowOrNeverElensil , actually i mean $K>J$

Answer (score 1):

Letting $f(x)=2^{x^2}$, $f^\prime(x)\gt 0$ if $x\gt0.$

Hence, we know $y=f(x)$ is a strictly monotone increasing function in $x\gt0.$

Comment: Thanks mathlove, actually i mean $K>J$

Comment: @juantheron: You've already got $J\lt I, K\lt L$, so $J\lt I\lt K\lt L$, right?

Comment: You are welcome!